# jQuery show error message after $.post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this :

- HTML : form + jquery
- Controller

I post the form via jQuery, in the controller, there an error somewhere in function I used, I set the status code to 500. I'd like in the ".error" of $.post show the content of my view. As you see I tested several alert but I never see the content of the view

**HTML**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save","Customer"))
{   
}

var jqxhr = $.post("Customer/Save", function () {
    alert("success");
})
.success(function () {})
.error( function (jqXHR, status, error) {
    alert(jqXHR);
    alert(status),
    alert(error);
 })
.complete(function () {});
```

**Controller **

```
public ActionResult Save(MyModel model)
{
    //Action1 here
    //....

    if(Actiion1 failed)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500
        return PartialView("Error");
    }       
    return View("MyView");
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: you don't need to add Error Partial View and set Response.StatusCode=500; you need only get responseText property of returned data on error function as in my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be checking the `responseText` member of `jqXHR`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   did you check if your async post request is coming into controller? If yes then instead of sending the partial view back, try to send some dummy string and check.
```

Hope this helps.

Abby

Answer (score 0):

i have done it with this way. on page i have included this code.

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function (request, err) {
            //            if (x.status == 0) {
            //                alert('you are offline!!\n Check you network.');
            //            } else 
            if (request.status == 404) {
                alert('page not found');
            } else if (request.status == 500) {
                $('body').html(request.responseText);
            } else if (err == 'parsererror') {
                alert('parse error');
            } else if (err == 'timeout') {
                alert('timeout');
            } else {
                alert('unhandled exception.\n' + x.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
  });
```

you can see that i am setting body html property to result text when error.status is 500. it will set error page content to body